# Unchecked radiobuttons when the program starts while the variable is StringVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button, tk-toolkit

Here I get all of the radiobuttons checked when the program starts. However, I want none of them to be checked at first, only a user can then choose one of them:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

var = StringVar()

l = Label(root)
l.pack()

def f():
    l.config(text=var.get())

rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="First", variable=var, value='a', command=f)
rb1.pack()

rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Second", variable=var, value='b', command=f)
rb2.pack()
```

But not the same with IntVar:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

var = IntVar()

l = Label(root)
l.pack()

def f():
    l.config(text=var.get())

rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="First", variable=var, value=1, command=f)
rb1.pack()

rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Second", variable=var, value=2, command=f)
rb2.pack()
```

When I run this program it works the way I want -- none of the radiobuttons are checked as the program starts and I decide to choose one of them.

But when the variable is StringVar, it doesn't work out. I want to figure out why it doesn't. I've looked for any solution in a few sources, but I couldn't find anything helpful. So decided to ask here. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: From a usability point of view, this is bad design and not how radiobuttons are designed to work. Radiobuttons should represent exactly one of many choices. Not zero or one, exactly one. If you want them all unchecked, add one more radiobutton with a choice like "None" or "Undecided" or whatever makes sense in the context of your app.

Comment: I know its design is terrible but It's just a small example. I got stuck in another program but that's longer so I decided to find out the exact problem and ask it here, instead of writing the "complex" program here.

Comment: Ah, I know it's a not a big problem, I just feel stuck! Could you please edit my code? I tried but got nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set your radiobutton to ' ' == "empty var" so none are selected, but this makes no sense as mentioned by @bryan Oakley.

Im not usre i'm within best practices by adding values to a list for creating radiobuttons, but this should allow you to have unselected radiobuttons

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def f():
    l.config(text=var.get())

var = StringVar()
var.set(' ')  #EVEN without the None value, this will allow empty radiobuttons on init. NOT Recommended

values = ['None', 'a', 'b']

l = Label(root, width=20)
l.pack()

for vset in values:
    rb = Radiobutton(root, text="First", variable=var, value=vset, command=f)
    rb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, @glls! var.set(' ') was what I was looking for! :) Appreciated!